# How do you add a QPushButtonGroup to a GridLayout Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, containers

I'm trying to create a puzzle game with the following layout:

[image]

It's a basic slide puzzle so clicking on a button will swap its value with an adjacent button only if it's empty.

I'm having trouble adding buttons from the QButtonGroup container to the QGridLayout. I can't seem to find any relevant examples online about this issue. I can access the individual buttons in the button group and modify their values, but I can't seem to get them to display properly in the window. Any help would be appreciated!

Header File:

```
/** A single tile in the GUI of the 9 puzzle */
class Tile : public QPushButton {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Tile(int tileNumber);
    int getNumber() {return m_Number;}
private:
    int m_Number;

};

/** A view for the puzzle */
class PuzzleView : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PuzzleView(PuzzleModel* model);
public slots:
    void refresh();
    void tryToSlide(QAbstractButton* button);
private:
    PuzzleModel *m_Model;
    QGridLayout *m_Layout;
    QButtonGroup m_Tiles;
};
```

Implementation file:

```
Tile::Tile(int tileNumber): m_Number(tileNumber) {
}


PuzzleView::PuzzleView(PuzzleModel* model) : m_Model(model) {
    // Create the buttons
    // This is where I'm having an issue (simplified to one button for clarity)

    m_Tiles.addButton(new Tile(1), 0);
    m_Layout = new QGridLayout();
    m_Layout->addWidget(m_Tiles.button(0), 0, 0); 

    connect (&m_Tiles, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)),
             this, SLOT(tryToSlide(QAbstractButton*)));
}
```

Comment: `m_Layout` is not assigned to any widget. Provide `parent` parameter equal `this`.

Comment: @MarekR what do you mean by assigning m_Layout to a widget? Do I have to create a QWidget instance and assign that to m_Layout?

Comment: Fix line `m_Layout = new QGridLayout(this);` or add `setLayout(m_Layout);`.